# What is the mathematical expression for fundamental quantum of flux?

Tags: superconductivity

Somewhere it is written as $\frac{h}{2e}$ and somewhere $\frac{hc}{2e}$. So what is the expression?

Comment: Those two don't have the same dimensions.

Comment: I edited the question now.

Comment: Yes but only over of those has dimensions of flux.

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=98sCQCPCOJIC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=fundamental+quantum+of+flux&source=bl&ots=ZfitVEieVX&sig=RzSQD9zDimyIwlEQXgv7rJVZIvg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK1JH47anTAhVLuY8KHW4XAnMQ6AEIdzAS#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20quantum%20of%20flux&f=false                         see this link

Comment: Thanks for helping.h/2e have units of flux. But in some books and the link above have written hc/2e . If u will get something else about it, please reply .

Comment: Probably the one with $c$ is using the CGS system.

Comment: Yes but how expression changes with change of unit system. One more Example - larmor precession frequency in si units is eB/2m and in cgs units is eB/2mc.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's just a problem of SI <-> CGS conversion, the transformation from one system to the other is NOT automatic, since there are many CGS systems in fact, see [the Wikipedia entry for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units#Electromagnetic_units_in_various_CGS_system).

You can check the Schrödinger equation of a free charged particle for your problem. In SI, in reads

$$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\mathbf{i}e}{\hbar}A\right)^{2}\Psi=0 \;;\;\text{SI}$$

and in CGS unit it reads

$$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\mathbf{i}e}{\hbar c}A\right)^{2}\Psi=0 \;;\;\text{CGS}$$

so the unit of the vector potential is not the same in both systems.

If you want to absorb the gauge potential in both systems, you can take $\Psi=e^{\mathbf{i}\Phi/\Phi_{0}}\Psi_{0}$ in both system, except

$$\Phi=\int A\cdot dx=\iint B\cdot dS\;;\;\Phi_{0}\sim\dfrac{h}{e}\;;\;\text{SI}$$

$$\Phi=\int A\cdot dx=\iint B\cdot dS\;;\;\Phi_{0}\sim\dfrac{hc}{e}\;;\;\text{CGS}$$

You can check the SI unit because they are well documented see [the Wikipedia page on Weber unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_(unit)) for instance,

$$\dfrac{h}{e}\equiv\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}^{2}\cdot\text{s}^{-2}\cdot\text{A}^{-1}$$

in SI unit. The factor of $2$ in the definition of $\Phi_{0}$ is just a matter of convention when one deals with superconductivity, since the unit charge is the one of Cooper pairs.